# Look for repeated values in an array of orders and replace

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I searched everywhere but could not solve my doubts.

I created a system of order, and this code is where rescues all orders. It turns out that if a request is made of the same item at different times, it shows two separate items in the list. I like to search inside the array orders of the same product and just add the quantities, showing only a product in the list of the quantities added. Someone please help me?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    // temp user array
    $pedidos = array();
    $pedidos["cid"] = $row["id"];
    $pedidos["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $pedidos["qtd"] = $row["qtd"];
    $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT name FROM produtos WHERE id = '".$pedidos["pid"]."'"));
    $pedidos["name"] = $name["name"];
    $cob = $row["cob"];
    $dobro = $row["dobro"];

    $price = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT valor FROM produtos WHERE id = '".$pedidos["pid"]."'"));
    $pedidos["price"] = $price["valor"];

    if($cob != "false"){
        $cobprice = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT valor FROM produtos WHERE name = 'cob'"));
        if($dobro){
            $cobprice["valor"] *= 2;
        }
        $pedidos["price"] += $cobprice["valor"];
        $pedidos["price"] = (string)$pedidos["price"];
        $pedidos["name"] = $pedidos["name"]." + Cobertura";
    }
    array_push($response["conta"], $pedidos);
}
```

Comment: You don't need two different MySQL select. Use it like "select name, valor from ...". What cob is?

Comment: You're right. I fixed it! But my problem stays...

Comment: So you want to group the item by its name and sum up the product amount?

Comment: Yes, for example: I have in the table orders two diferent orders of the same product, like this:

productid=206, name=ice_cream, quantity=2, price= 3.00
productid=206, name=ice_cream, quantity=1, price= 1.50

then the result:
productid=206, name=ice_cream, quantity=3, price= 4.50

ps.: I DON'T wish to add the values in the database, only for display.

Answer (score 0):

to protect repeated use this code

```
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta,"SELECT DISTINCT name FROM produtos WHERE id = '".$pedidos["pid"]."'"));
```

sql DISTINCT read tutorial about this may help you.